# Having trouble deciphering this function space notation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation, fluid-dynamics

I am working through some fluid mechanics and I can't seem to find a precise definition anywhere for this function space notation:

$$z(\alpha,t) \in C^1 \left( [-T,T]; C[0,2\pi] \right)$$

I am specifically looking at the bottom of page 332 (Proposition 8.6) in Majda and Bertozzi's *Vorticity and Incompressible Flow*. I have seen several other examples of this notation such as

$$L^\infty (0,T;C^{1,\alpha})$$
and
$$C(0,T;H^1).$$

I think I get the general idea - for instance $L^\infty (0,T;C^{1,\alpha})$ is something like the set of functions $f(t,x)$ that are $L^\infty$ in time on the interval $[0,T]$ and $C^{1,\alpha}$ in space (could be wrong about that), but it also seems that the Holder norm is interacting with the $L^\infty$ norm somehow.

Does anybody have a good definition of these kind of spaces or know of a reference that defines them thoroughly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that the function $z(\alpha, t)$ is regarded as a $C^1$ function of $\alpha$ (in $C^1[0, 2\pi])$) for each $t \in [-T,T]$: $t \mapsto z_{\alpha}(t):=z(\alpha,t)$. You would read it as "$C^1$ function in $[-T,T]$, with values in $C^1[0, 2\pi]$".

Comment: Thanks for the response - so for $f(t,x)\in L^\infty (0,T;C^{1,\alpha})$, would that mean it is a $C^{1,\alpha}$ function in $x$ for every $t\in[0,T]$? And where does the $L^\infty$ come in?

Comment: @Thomas It is $L^{\infty}$ in $t$.